# Why are some songs available on 7digital.com not available in the Ubuntu One Music Store?

Tags: ubuntu-one, music, rhythmbox

What is the reason that some songs, which are available on 7Digital.com (My country-region) are not available in ubuntu-one-store?
As example the last album of "Nine Lashes - The Intervention" was not listed by Rhythmbox...

I would like to support canonical on this way but so i have no joiz...

Comment: It would help if you would state which country you are in. Most likely you are getting the World Store inside Rhythmbox for Ubuntu One.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read here: https://one.ubuntu.com/music/#toc_4 there are different regions for the U1 Music store. This is the actual situation, and I don't know if it will change soon or later.